# React: add body class only to certain components in useEffect hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I am using React 16.8.6 and hooks. I am new to hooks.

I have a component loaded in a route I need to add a body class to.  When the user leaves this page, I need the class removed.  I am using

```
  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.className = 'signin';
  }, []);
```

This correctly adds the class to the body tag. Except when I navigate to another page, the class remains.  If I **reload** the second page it's gone.

How do I remove the class when the component unmounts when the route changes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `useEffect` hook supports a cleanup function that runs when the component unmounts

```
useEffect(() => {
  document.body.className = 'signin';
  return () => { document.body.className = ''; }
});
```

See the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup).

Comment: This works great.  It leaves an empty class attribute (which is not a problem, but I'm wondering how to remove).

Can this be done to add to and remove from other classes already on the body tag?

Comment: @Steve I presume you mean you want to omit _only_ `signin` leaving any existing classes intact? `document.body.className = document.body.className.replace('signin', '')`

Comment: @Steve you may or may not prefer to use [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), you'll get the same outcome either way, but the API might be cleaner.

Answer (score 9):

If your effect returns a function, it will act as a cleanup.

```
useEffect(() => {
  document.body.classList.add('signin');

  return function cleanup() {
    document.body.classList.remove('signin');
  };
}, []);
```

You can check out [Effects with cleanup](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup) in the documentation